# Accees Hue error - 1045

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hue

I'm trying to connect the HUE and show this error:[image]

Somenone help me please!

Answer (score 1):

```
Access denied for user 'hue'@'localhost'
```

It means your database (= MySQL) doesn't permit `hue` user to login from localhost.
Please follow the procedure; [Using an External Database for Hue Using the Command Line](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_hue_database.html)

Especially,

```
mysql> create database hue;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> grant all on hue.* to 'hue'@'localhost' identified by '<secretpassword>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```